# How should I index a UUID in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, index, uuid

I'm new to PostgreSQL and somewhat new to databases in general. Is there an established way of how we should index [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) values in Postgres? I'm split between using hashing and using a trie, unless there's already something built-in that it uses automatically. Whatever I use is going to be handling huge amounts of data.

The SP-GiST operator family "text_ops" indexes using a trie. Because UUIDs are quite long and very dissimilar, these sound appealing even though I would only ever do full match searches.

There's also a hash option. Hashing is O(1), and I won't need to do any comparisons besides equality of course, but because UUIDs are quite long, I'm afraid that generating hashes from them would waste a lot of time.

Or is this something that depends too much on system and use specifics?

I'd rather use *bigserial* in most cases, but I've been told to use *uuid* for this. We need *uuid* because we might have multiple servers using different databases, so there isn't a guarantee that we'll have unique bigints. We could use a different sequence (and seed) for each server, but it's still not as flexible as UUIDs. For example, we wouldn't be able to migrate database entries from one server to another without converting the IDs and their references everywhere.

Comment: I believe ["federated database"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) is the buzzword for your situation. And, yes, UUIDs are the solution for that. That was the very reason UUIDs were invented decades ago: for sharing data amongst distributed systems without centralized coordination.

Comment: Months later: Indeed, the "federated database" Basil Bourque brought up is what we're going for. Not only do we have multiple servers, but we have clients (which can be thought of as more parts of the federated DB) creating IDs while offline, too. That's why we use UUIDs.

Comment: Years later: I'm cringing remembering what I did here. All we needed as bigserial primary keys for relations, not uuids, and the uuids were much slower. Uuids can be useful to store with a secondary index (default btree) purely as a key to communicate with the client instead of exposing the sequential one, for example as a post ID on a social app. If we ever sharded the DB, the internal IDs might change, that's fine.

On the algos side, btree makes no sense here. And hashmaps aren't really constant-time unless you're assuming everything is in uniform-speed RAM, which it's not here.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use PostgreSQL's built-in [`uuid` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html), and [create](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) a regular b-tree index on it.

There is no need to do anything special. This will result in an optimal index, and will also store the `uuid` field in as compact a form as is currently practical.

(Hash indexes in PostgreSQL prior to version 10 were not crash-safe and were really a historical relic that tended to perform no better than a b-tree anyway. Avoid them. On PostgreSQL 10 they've been made crash-safe and had some performance improvements made so you may wish to consider them.)

If for some reason you could not use the `uuid` type, you would generally create a b-tree on the text representation or, preferably, a `bytea` representation of the uuid.

Comment: While the statement regarding `hash` indexes versus `b-tree` is a commonly held belief, I think it would be helpful to cite sources for such a claim.

Comment: As of PostgreSQL 10, `hash` indexes are now crash-safe. That said, `hash` indexes can only be used with `=`, so if you need any other operators, `b-tree` is still preferable.

Comment: A couple of years later, in my experience, `hash` hasn't been much faster than `b-tree`, even in Postgres 10. But since hash indexes take so much less disk space than b-tree, it might be faster in a setup where big indexes become a problem, which I feel hasn't been the case for me. Well I'll keep an eye out now that I can actually use them safely in v10.

Comment: There are some good write ups on hash index perf improvements in v10 and v11: http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2017/09/postgresqls-hash-indexes-are-now-cool.html - http://amitkapila16.blogspot.com/2017/03/hash-indexes-are-faster-than-btree.html

Answer (score 10):

BRIN-index? If you use time-based (version 1) UUIDs then they are generated so that their value increase. In which case BRIN is suitable.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/brin-intro.html :

> BRIN stands for Block Range Index. **BRIN is designed for handling very
>   large tables in which certain columns have some natural correlation
>   with their physical location** within the table. A **block range is a
>   group of pages that are physically adjacent in the table;** for each
>   block range, some summary info is stored by the index. For example, a
>   table storing a store's sale orders might have a date column on which
>   each order was placed, and most of the time the entries for earlier
>   orders will appear earlier in the table as well; a table storing a ZIP
>   code column might have all codes for a city grouped together
>   naturally.
>
> BRIN indexes can satisfy queries via regular bitmap index scans, and
>   will return all tuples in all pages within each range if the summary
>   info stored by the index is consistent with the query conditions. The
>   query executor is in charge of rechecking these tuples and discarding
>   those that do not match the query conditions — in other words, these
>   indexes are lossy. **Because a BRIN index is very small, scanning the
>   index adds little overhead compared to a sequential scan, but may
>   avoid scanning large parts of the table that are known not to contain
>   matching tuples.**
>
> The specific data that a BRIN index will store, as well as the
>   specific queries that the index will be able to satisfy, depend on the
>   operator class selected for each column of the index. **Data types
>   having a linear sort order can have operator classes that store the
>   minimum and maximum value within each block range, for instance;
>   geometrical types might store the bounding box for all the objects in
>   the block range.**
>
> The size of the block range is determined at index creation time by
>   the pages_per_range storage parameter. The number of index entries
>   will be equal to the size of the relation in pages divided by the
>   selected value for pages_per_range. Therefore, the smaller the number,
>   the larger the index becomes (because of the need to store more index
>   entries), but at the same time the summary data stored can be more
>   precise and more data blocks can be skipped during an index scan.

Perfect for huge and "mostly" ordered data.

See this post for some benchmarks:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/16/brin-index-for-postgresql-dont-forget-the-benefits/

They genereated a 1.3 GB table of naturally ordered data (timestamps incemented). Then they generated a BRIN index (with pages_per_range = 32) and a B-Tree index on this database. Then they compared the SELECT execution time and the size of the indices. What they got:

B-Tree:

> Planning Time: 22.225 ms Execution Time: **2.657 ms**
>
> public | testtab_date_idx | index | postgres | testtab | **171 MB**

BRIN:

> Planning Time: 0.272 ms Execution Time: **87.703 ms**
>
> public | testtab_date_brin_idx | index | postgres | testtab | **64 kB**

meanwhile with no-index it would be:

> Planning Time: 0.296 ms Execution Time: **1766.454 ms**

Just to give a sense of orders.

What is important to discuss furthermore is the complexity of index update after INSERT of the two. While for BRIN it is O(1), since you write sequentially on the next free space on the memory and accordingly create new BRIN entries, however for B-Tree as we well know it is O(logN) ([B-Trees](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/mluukkai/tirak2010/B-tree.pdf)) (higher the tree longer it takes).

Comment: I think this is a very good answer. I don't understand all this hate...

Comment: @Najib, your edits look good and earned my upvote.  My initial comment was meant to be constructive as the [answer in its initial form](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/264867/1) didn't do much to explain the links.  I hope you see the benefits you've now provided with a better explanation rather than just pasting in links without proper context.  Everyone benefits from better answers, which is why I left the initial feedback.  Sorry that your initial interaction with the community wasn't different, but I hope you stick around and make the community the place you'd like it to become.

Comment: Also, I didn't downvote your answer at any point (I only downvote when answers are blatantly *wrong*).  Like you, my initial interaction with the community wasn't exactly what I was expecting, but I've found this to be a great place for information and feedback.  Don't let a few downvotes get the best of you, and I hope to see you stick around.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Thanks! Yes, I completely understood you, your comment was right, I shouldn't have written a short, shallow answer and I realized that soon and changed it for the better. However I think the way the pointing system works in SO could be improved, or maybe I took it too seriosuly. Anyways, thanks and hope I could contribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the RFC 4122 compliant UUID versions/variants are lexicographically sortable. Even the time-based ones - you can see this if you go to [any online generator](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version1) and generate a few. The first hex segment varies quickly, while the more stable hex segments come after. This is the _opposite_ of what you want for a lexicographically sortable value. This is why SQL Server has the noncompliant NEWSEQUENTIALID. If one is willing to go non-RFC for PostGres, there's [ULIDs](https://github.com/ulid/spec) which are made to be sortable.

Comment: It is worth noting that as of PostGres v12, [only b-trees support unique indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.7:~:text=Only%20B%2Dtree%20currently%20supports%20unique%20indexes). This means one cannot use a BRIN index as an PK. One could use an `integer` or `bigint` as the PK then have a ULID column that's BRIN indexed, but I would question whether the complexity is worth the benefits. B-trees work well with ULIDs since they're lexicographically sortable - i.e. new rows will only append to the tree rather than randomly inserting into it.

Comment: You are right actually. Weird I remembered postgres [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/uuid-ossp.html) generates timestamp-first v1s. But hey then no. U r right it should be lexicographically sortable, ULID looks interesting.

Comment: Besides the non-lexicographically sortable UUIDv1 through UUDv5, the yes-lexicographically sortable UUIDv6 through UUIDv8 are gaining in momentum. And, for PostgreSQL, there are now a number of implementations of so-called sequential UUIDs: https://blog.bigsmoke.us/2023/06/04/postgresql-sequential-uuids

Answer (score 3):

Hash indexes are missing in action in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL knows it needs hash indexes, and that it's code for hash indexes is old and moldy, but they don't remove it because they are waiting for someone to come along and overhaul hash indexing. See this thread:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4407.1115698257@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: Hash indexes work well in PostgreSQL under some circumstances, but I recently found they caused my queries to return no results when I tried optimizing with hash indexes on built-in UUID data type primary & foreign keys. There truly are benefits to hash indexes, if only they worked for all data types, and PostgreSQL devs know this, they're just too lazy to fix it themselves, and they keep their code situated as if they are praying to/for their eventual savior.

Comment: Someone has rescued hash indexes, I'm guessing because they play a critical role in data partitioning, which Pg10 has been focusing on: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Crash_Safe.2C_Replicable_Hash_Indexes But they still don't give you everything I've seen theoretically useful in college database class ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the default index type (ie B-Tree).

Although there's no much in it, `hash` was not faster. `hash` doesn't support `unique` either (if you need that).

Results obtained given:

- A column type `uuid` plus about 150 bytes worth of other columns
- 10M rows
- creating each index type then running `analyze mytable`
- running a `select * from mytable where myuuid = '<some uuid>'::uuid`
- middle timing value (including tool overhead, all results were within a narrowish range)

| Index type | Milliseconds |
| --- | --- |
| No index | 3600 |
| btree (default) | 90 |
| unique btree | 100 |
| hash | 100 |
| unique hash | not supported |

Comment: Yeah, it's not intuitive, but I was also seeing hash performing worse despite it only working for one particular operation (equality).

Answer (score 2):

The solution as of 2023 is to use a *sequential* UUID algorithm that is `uuid` compatible. There are quite a few [sequential (sortable by byte sequence) UUID implementation for PostgreSQL](https://blog.bigsmoke.us/2023/06/04/postgresql-sequential-uuids) now. My favorite one is the [`pg_uuidv7`](https://github.com/fboulnois/pg_uuidv7) extension by Florian Boulnois.

UUIDv7 is one of [three new sequential UUID variants proposed](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-01.html) as an extension to [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122).

Comment: Even with UUIDv7, have you had a chance to compare the space consumption and query performance between B-Tree and Hash indexes for your databases, in more recent versions of PostgreSQL?

Comment: It looks like "Expires: 28 October 2021" means it wasn't approved?